# Solving for a matrix in an equation with trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, trace

I want to solve the following equation for the $m\times m$ matrix $X$:
$$2X^T(A^TA)=-2\mathrm{trace}(X)I+V,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, $A$ is a $t\times m$ known matrix, and $V$ is an $m\times m$ known matrix. Assume that $t$ is less than $m$ so, in this case, $A^TA$ is a singular matrix.

I looked at the question in 
[Solving matrix equation involving trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470658/solving-matrix-equation-involving-trace) 
but it did not help me because of the singularity of $A^TA$.

Also, in the same link, they that said this kind of equations can be solve with vectorization. I searched the internet but could not find anything about this topic: could someone help me with that please?

Thank you.

Comment: I took the liberty to change $T$ with $t$ in order to not raise confusion between the transpose of $A$ and its number of row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
B &= A^TA \cr
W &= \tfrac{1}{2}V^T \cr
\tau &= {\rm tr}(X) \cr
}$$
Divide your equation by $2$ and transpose it 
$$\eqalign{
 BX &= W - \tau I \cr
}$$
The general solution of this linear equation can be written in terms of the Moore-Penrose inverse $B^+$ and the nullspace projector applied to an arbitrary matrix $Y$. 
$$\eqalign{
 X_s &= B^+(W-\tau I) + (I-B^+B)Y \cr
}$$
Be aware that your equation might not have *any* solutions.

To see this, multiply each side by the transposed projector.
$$\eqalign{
 (I-BB^+)(BX) &= (I-BB^+)(W - \tau I) \cr
  0 &= (I-BB^+)W - \tau (I-BB^+) \cr
  (I-BB^+)W &= \tau (I-BB^+) \\
  V(I-B^+B) &= (2\tau) (I-B^+B) \cr
}$$
A solution only exists when $W$ or $V$, satisfies the projected equation for some $\tau.\,$ So in some sense, the choice of $A$ restricts your choice of $V$; they are not independent of each other.

Another way of looking at it: *every* column of $(I-B^+B)$ must be a linear combination of the eigenvectors of $V$ associated with a single eigenvalue, $\lambda=2\tau$.

$\tau$ can be calculated by equating the traces.
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(X) &= {\rm tr}(X_s) \\
\tau &= B^+:W^T - \tau B^+:I + (I- B^+B)^T:Y \\
\tau\,(1+I:B^+) &= W^T:B^+ + (I-B^+B):Y \\
\tau &= \frac{W^T:B^+ + (I-B^+B):Y}{1+I:B^+} \\
}$$
Substitute this value into the expression for $X_s\\$

**NB:** In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
Properties of the trace allow terms in a colon product to be rearranged in lots of ways.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
}$$

Comment: Does that mean no unique solution to this problem?

Comment: There is no unique solution, but if you set $Y$ to zero you'll get the least-squares solution.

Comment: take this example A=[1 3 2; 3 1 4];
Y=[2 1 .3; 1 .2 3; .1 .3 .5]; 
V=[.2 .3 2; 1 .1 .2; .7 .5 .3]; X will be  [1.1723    0.6921    0.2063; 
    0.4328   -0.4655    0.1885;
   -1.0764   -0.2512   -0.3200] which does not satisfy my original equation. something wrong

Comment: @AymenKareem Thanks for the counter-example. I've updated my answer. I can see what went wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the matrices are real. Let $r$ be the rank of $A$. Orthogonally diagonalise $A^TA$ as $Q(D\oplus0)Q^T$, where $D$ is a $r\times r$ positive diagonal matrix. Let also
$$
X^T=Q\pmatrix{X_1&X_2\\ X_3&X_4}Q^T,\quad V=Q\pmatrix{V_1&V_2\\ V_3&V_4}Q^T,
$$
where both $X_1$ and $V_1$ are $r\times r$. The equation can then be rewritten as
$$
2\pmatrix{X_1D&0\\ X_3D&0}=-2\operatorname{tr}(X)I+\pmatrix{V_1&V_2\\ V_3&V_4},
$$
i.e.
$$
\pmatrix{X_1&0\\ X_3&0}=\pmatrix{\frac12\left(-2\operatorname{tr}(X)I_r+V_1\right)D^{-1}&V_2\\ \frac12V_3D^{-1}&-2\operatorname{tr}(X)I_{m-r}+V_4}.
$$
Therefore, it is solvable if and only if $V_2=0$ and $V_4=2tI_{m-r}$ for some number $t$. If this is the case, the general solution is given by
$$
X^T=Q\pmatrix{\frac12\left(-2tI_r+V_1\right)D^{-1}&X_2\\ \frac12V_3D^{-1}&X_4}Q^T
$$
where $X_2$ is arbitrary and $X_4$ is any matrix whose trace is $\alpha=t-\frac12\operatorname{tr}\left(\left(-2tI_r+V_1\right)D^{-1}\right)$ (so that the trace of $X$ is $t$).

If you don't want to use partitioned matrices, you may rewrite the above solution as follows. Let $P=A^TA$. Then the equation is solvable if and only if $V(I-P^+P)=2t(I-P^+P)$ for some $t\in\mathbb R$. If this is the case, the general solution is given by
$$
X^T=\frac12(-2tI+V)P^+ + \left(\alpha I + M - \frac1n\operatorname{tr}(M(I-P^+P))I\right)(I-P^+P)
$$
where $M$ is an arbitrary matrix and
$$
\alpha = t-\frac12\operatorname{tr}\left((-2tI+V)P^+\right).
$$

Comment: Can you give example with numbers? Like the one in my comments in the answer above.

Comment: @AymenKareem I have already given you a solution formula in my answer. Just pick an arbitrary $M$ and plug in $A$ and $V$ to determine $t$ and $X^T$. For your example, the equation is not solvable because $V(I-P^+P)$ is not a multiple of $I-P^+P$. You may verify using any computer algebra package that your $X$ does not satisfies the equation with the given $A,V$.