# Solving matrix equation involving complicated dependence on trace expression

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, trace

Given a symmetric and positive definite matrix $B$, solve the following matrix equation for matrix $X$ $$ X B - B^{-1} \frac{\mathrm{tr} \left( B^{-3} X B \right)}{\mathrm{tr} \left( B^{-4} \right)} = 0 $$

---

I tried it with the strategies from [Solving matrix equation involving trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470658/solving-matrix-equation-involving-trace) and [Solving for a matrix in an equation with trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950935/solving-for-a-matrix-in-an-equation-with-trace), but for the given equation, this only leads to trivial results such as

$$\mathrm{tr}(B^{-3} X B)= \mathrm{tr}(B^{-3} X B)$$

Additionally, is there even a general strategy to solve this type of equations? I can only stare at the equation and hope for some insight right now. Is there even a solution? Or are there infinitely many?

Comment: Since $\operatorname{tr}(\cdots)/\operatorname{tr}(\cdots)$ is just a scalar, $X$ must be of the form $cB^{-2}$, which indeed produces all the solutions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks it thought about this and it first felt strange, that the complicated trace part does not play a role here, but your suggestion now feels correct. Thanks!